# Javascript Function and Async Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my first post here and I was hoping to get some clarity on an issue I am having with retrieving data from a $.getJSON call and then moving that data into an array.  Please note that I am relatively new to javascript and jQuery so if my code does not look properly organized that is just from a lack of experience.

I have a function that loads a master container with a series of div elements that have the name of a folder from my computer, specifically a folder that contains images.  I currently have 8 different folders with images and the function loads the master container with div's representing these folders but the container is set up so that it only shows 6 folders.

What I am trying to accomplish in the code below is a slideshow of sorts where when the user clicks on an arrow (left or right), the boxes, which are just css styled div's, slide to the left or right off of the screen and a new box is loaded from the opposite side.  When working correctly the containing div will show 6 folders.

The issue I am having is that on the arrow click, I retrieve the data, and then populate a new array with the foldernames.  I then use a shift and push to shift the array elements. Then when it comes time to repopulate the master container with the shifted array I am losing the folder names.

So in the first for loop the foldernames would be for example ("My Vacation Photos", "Birthday Photos", etc..)

I then perform the shift and push and then set up a new for loop to repopulate the master container but at this point the foldernames are coming back as ("0", "1", "2", etc...)

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

```
$(document).on('click', '#leftarrow', function ()
        {
            $('.imageFolders').animate({ left: "-=175px" }, 750);

            var jsonFile = 'http://www.johndavidhock.net/views/about/json/jsonObject.json';
            $.getJSON(jsonFile, function (data)
            {
                var folderArray = [];

                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    for (var foldername in data)
                    {
                        folderArray.push(foldername);
                        //foldername is coming back correctly, i.e. "My Vacation Photos", "Birthday Photos", etc..
                    }

                    var x = folderArray.shift();
                    folderArray.push(x);

                    var destination = $('#masterNavigator');
                    destination.html("");
                    for (var foldername in folderArray)
                    {
                        destination.append('<div id="' + foldername + '" class="imageFolders" ;>' + foldername + '</div>');
                        //foldername is coming back incorrectly, i.e. "0", "1", etc..
                    }
                }, 600);
            });
        });
```

Comment: `for(x in y)` iterates the keys of y ... an array's keys are 0, 1, 2 ... perhaps `for(x of y)` is more suited ... or better yet, `y.forEach(function(x) { ...})` - note: your issue has nothing to do with async calls

Comment: another option is use the key to access array: folderArray[foldername]

Comment: Yes!!! thank you.  I changed the second loop and added a variable to get the foldername:  var myFolderName = folderArray[foldername];  It's the easy things like this that keep me up at night!  Thanks again for the quick response!!

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTON: put `debugger;` as the first line of both your "$.getJSON()" and "setTimeout)" functions, then single-step through the code in Chrome Developer tools (or equivalent).  Here's a good tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments, but I just realized something and wanted to post something in case someone else does as well.  Hopefully this will make sense.  The initial load comes from a json file and that works fine.  But when the arrow is clicked I need to reload the master container and shift to either left or right but at that point I can not use the json file because that contains the original order.  I need to get the id's of the loaded divs and put that into an array and then shift it.